# Elesh Norn and 2/2 Creature + Aura Entering at the same time

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We have a [Elesh Norn, Grand Cenobite](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elesh%20Norn%2C%20Grand%20Cenobite) in play and another player casts [Triumphant Reckoning](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Triumphant%20Reckoning) bringing back a 2/2 creature and an aura giving +1/+1. Can the creature now enter as a 3/3 and will it therefore survive? I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although [Triumphant Reckoning](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Triumphant%20Reckoning) explicitly forbids this interaction, [Rise to Glory](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rise%20to%20Glory) does allow a player to return a creature *then* an aura, so the aura could be attached to the creature.

In that case, the 2/2 with an aura giving it +1/+1 would survive. The reason is that creatures with 0 toughness only die when state based actions are checked, which happens after the card has finished resolving. So even though there was a 0/0 on the battlefield, it's still valid for the aura to enchant it.

You could also produce the same interaction with Rise to Glory reanimating a [Hangarback Walker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hangarback%20Walker) and an [All That Glitters](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=All%20That%20Glitters).

Comment: exactly what i needed to know! thank you so much

Answer (score 8):

**No, the aura cannot be attached to that creature, so the creature cannot enter as a 3/3.**

Triumphant Reckoning has this ruling on its Gatherer page:

> An Aura returning to the battlefield this way can't be attached to anything else entering the battlefield at the same time. If it enchants a permanent, you have to choose one already on the battlefield.

Comment: Thank you so much! But i read controversial stuff un other sites about this rule. I marked the other question as correct answer because it also answers questions arousing since elesh norn is in play